# Is it not possible to read QR codes in an android application without having a third party app installed?

Tags: android, qr-code

I am looking at making use of QR codes in an application of mine.

I did some research / Googling and I found that this library is apparently a good option to use:
http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/news/

But I read there it says that is still needs an application that can read qr codes for it to work?

Is there not a library that just makes use of the camera and then decodes the qr code in the application that is using the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZBar can be installed as a library in the project, and used as any other activity. 
You can Check:

- https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner/blob/master/examples/ZBarScannerDemo/src/com/dm/zbar/android/examples/MainActivity.java

That's the example of how to use ZBAR to read a QR, in the `onActivityResult` you can handle the results (in this case the example makes a toast).

You can follow the installation explanation here:

- https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android

Answer (score 4):

If you need to scan QR codes in your application, this is the way to go :https://code.google.com/p/zxing/

You can also integrate the necessary libraries in your project in order to avoid to launch a scan using the `Intent` way (so a third-party app installed on your device would be necessary).

If you Google it, you'll find a lot of guides to do that: the first I got is http://www.androidaz.com/development/zxing-qr-reader-direct-integration but there's a plenty of tutorials out there.