# Implementing ZXing as original app

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, qr-code

I have a question on ZXing. Is there any way of launching their app as it is from mine? I've looked everywhere on the internet and haven't found an answer. As of now, I have created the bar-code in my app and run it as a direct link to Google, but I like the interface of the original app since it gives more information on the books being looked up. Mine just doesn't seem too practical in getting the bar-code and then having to look at a bunch of websites on Google to get the information of the book being looked up.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here: [Is it not possible to read QR codes in an android application without having a third party app installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402878/is-it-not-possible-to-read-qr-codes-in-an-android-application-without-having-a-t/19402992#19402992)

Basically you can integrate the ZXing code in your application and change the layout/logic as you need.
In this way you don't use the library with the `Intent` way but it will be directly integrated inside your application.